# Variable length Message over TCP Socket in C++

Tags: c++, tcp, network-programming

I was trying to send some length prefix data to the server, i have tried harder by using the code and solution posted by other people on stack overflow. Still looking how things are actually working using TCP.As i  don't know so much(about network programming but i am aware about theoretical concepts). i am writing what i have tried so far.Based on that i have some questions.

As we are using `Char Buffer[200] = "This is data"` on client side to send(using `send()` function) string and char type data to server(receiving using `recv()`function). Till here its okay but what if i need to send some variable length message with their length information ? , How i can encode length info to the message ?

```
for example:  0C     54 68 69 73 20 69 73 20 64 61 74 61     07    46 72 6f 6d 20 6d 65
           (length)  T  h   i  s    i   s     d  a  t  a   (length) F  r  o  m     m  e


How can i interpret these two message seperately from tcp stream  at the sever side ?
```

i dont know how length information can be sent separetly ?. Or if someone can understand my test case(given below in edit) to verify length information of the string.

**EDIT:** It seems okay but i just need verify a bit about prefix length. I am sending 20 bytes("This is data From me") to server. My recevied length size is 4 bytes(i dont know whats inside, i need to verify does the 4 bytes of length i received contain 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 00000 0001 0100). Thats it, so the way i thought to verify it by shifting length info by 2 bits right now it should look like ( 4 bytes of length i received contain 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 00000 0000 0101) in this case i should get only 5 characters i.e "This ". Do you know how can i verify this at server side ?

Client Code

```
int bytesSent;
int bytesRecv = SOCKET_ERROR;
char sendbuf[200] = "This is data From me";

int  nBytes = 200, nLeft, idx;
nLeft = nBytes;
idx = 0;
uint32_t varSize = strlen (sendbuf);
bytesSent = send(ConnectSocket,(char*)&varSize, 4, 0);
assert (bytesSent == sizeof (uint32_t));
std::cout<<"length information is in:"<<bytesSent<<"bytes"<<std::endl;
// code to make sure  all data has been sent
  while (nLeft > 0)
{
    bytesSent = send(ConnectSocket, &sendbuf[idx], nLeft, 0);
    if (bytesSent == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
      std::cerr<<"send() error: " << WSAGetLastError() <<std::endl;
      break;
    }
    nLeft -= bytesSent;
    idx += bytesSent;
}
bytesSent = send(ConnectSocket, sendbuf, strlen(sendbuf), 0);
 printf("Client: Bytes sent: %ld\n", bytesSent);
```

Server Code

```
     uint32_t  nlength;
int length_received = recv(m_socket,(char*)&nlength, 4, 0);
char *recvbuf = new char[nlength];
int byte_recived = recv(m_socket, recvbuf, nlength, 0);
```

Thanks

Comment: I think you will have to post some code - far less likely to get help without seeing the code.

Comment: @suspectus its there, please see edit.

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6946109/412080) is an answer to a similar question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you need to send variable-length data, you need to send the length of that data *before* the data itself.

In you code snippet above, you appear to be doing the opposite:

```
while (nLeft > 0)
{
    bytesSent = send(ConnectSocket, &sendbuf[idx], nLeft, 0);
    // [...]
}
bytesSent = send(ConnectSocket, sendbuf, strlen(sendbuf), 0);
```

Here you send the string first, and then the length.  How is the client going to be able to interpret that?  By the time the get the length, they have already pulled the string off the socket.

Instead, send the length first, and make sure you're explicit about the size of the size field:

```
const uint32_t varSize = strlen (sendbuf);
bytesSent = send(ConnectSocket, &varSize, sizeof (varSize), 0);
assert (bytesSent == sizeof (uint32_t));
while (nLeft > 0)
{
    bytesSent = send(ConnectSocket, &sendbuf[idx], nLeft, 0);
    // [...]
}
```

You might also consider not sending variable-length data at all.  Fixed-width binary protocols are easier to parse on the receiving side in general.  You could always send string data in a fixed-width field (say, 20 chars) and pad it out with spaces or `\0`'s.  This does waste some space on the wire, at least in theory.  If you are smart about the sizes of the fixed-width fields and what you send in them, you can be economical with this space in many cases.

Comment: It seems okay but i just need verify a bit about prefix length. I am sending 20 bytes("This is data From me") to server. My recevied length size is 4 bytes(i dont know whats inside, i need to verify does    the `4 bytes of length i received contain 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 00000 0001 0100`). Thats it, so the way i thought to verify it by shifting length info by 2 bits right now it should look like ( `4 bytes of length i received contain 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 00000 0000 0101`) in this case i should get only 5 characters i.e "This ". Do you know how can i verify this at server side ?

Comment: Please See edit in my question post! May be then you will understand what i meant to say.

Comment: @user3232405:  I'm sorry, I'm not getting what you're asking.  Can you clarify a bit?

Comment: Did you saw the server side code in my question ? Can you check which variable contain length information( `nlength` or how is it ?) ? and how receiver knows it  only needs to read 20 char from the string (because my  string length is 20 char). This is big question to understand that how server side know about the length.

Comment: John Can you Please split receiving side length information at  bits level, if possible.

Comment: @user3232405:  You've recieved the length of the variable-length string correctly; in to `nlength`.  That's how the receiver knows how many bytes to pull off of the socket.

Comment: John: Thank you! Your experiance have verified it for me, just kidding :). I tried it in debug mode, so its okay now. Another thing is that afer the end of my string data at console i am getting some garbage values,`This is data From me zzzzzz 1/2 1/2.....` Any idea ?

Comment: @user3232405:  It looks like you're either pulling too much data off of the socket, or not NULL-terminating the string you do get before printing it to the screen.  More likely the latter.

Comment: John: Its Strange to see if i shift memory bits i allocated for my receiving data `char *recvbuf = new char[nlength>>3]` it works fine no garbage value at allon the console. String is already null terminated even then i put \0 but it didn't work. Seems mysterious to me.

Comment: @JohnDibling Can the length be also sent in the same packet? For instance, like a HTTP message, can there something like a header `content-length` followed by actual data? On the other side read the header and allocate appropriate buffer length for the message data to fit?

Comment: @Djack:  Sure.  You can send the length and the payload all in one packet.  Just make sure the length comes first in the packet.