# socket BUFFER TO STRING

Tags: c++, c, sockets

I have an issues to convert my BUFFER into a string, I like to know how do I convert my BUFFER, recv from the socket.

I would like to have like my `db[0] = buffer`, which buffer contain a string like "helloworld", so if i want print `db[0]`, i would get "helloworld".

```
while(1){
    recv(newSocket, buffer, BUFFER_SIZE, 0);
    if(strcmp(buffer, "q") == 0){
        printf("Deconnexion de %s:%d\n", inet_ntoa(newAddr.sin_addr), ntohs(newAddr.sin_port));
        break;
    }else{
        printf("%s\n",buffer);//Client recu: 
        send(newSocket, buffer, strlen(buffer), 0);
        bzero(buffer, sizeof(buffer));

        db[i]=buffer;

        printf("%c",db[i]);

        //mysql_q(db[i]);// query function

        i++;
    }               
}
```

db type is a char array, but when i compile it gives me this error :

```
server.cpp:81:12: error: invalid conversion from ‘char*’ to ‘char’ [-fpermissive]
  db[i]=buffer;
```

Comment: What is the type of `db` and `buffer`, please show the definition ? error is quite clear `db[i]` is a `char` and `buffer` a `char *`. you should change `db` type

Comment: what kind of db? char[]?  you should not assign char* to char, db[i] is a char.  char* db[i] is better.

Comment: `c++` is not `c`. Choose a language.

Comment: this is my db and buffer type : char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
 char db[BUFFER_SIZE]; @Ôrel

Comment: @azures edit your question and insert complement inside. db[i] is a char and cannot receive a value of type char[].

Comment: You _had_ the string in `buffer` (albeit missing a terminating nul, perhaps) and then you cleared the buffer and then tried to do something completely nonsensical with it.  I think you need to take a break and think this over.  Also, what @JayKM said, but take that break first.

Answer (score 3):

You need to process return values of `recv` and `send` because they do incomplete reads and writes which must be handled.

Also, `recv` does not zero terminate received data, you need to do that yourself again to be able to call `strcmp`.

Most importantly, you need [a way to delimit complete messages](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6946109/412080).

In other words, you need to rewrite the whole piece with message extraction, partial read/write and error handling to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

if db[i] is a char array for which db should be double dimension array, you need to do a memcpy or strcpy (if you are sure that buffer will have null terminated string) to get contents of buffer to db[i].

```
db[i] = buffer
```

is wrong, thats why compilation error.