# why sys socket recv function don't fill data but return bytes length?

Tags: c++, c, linux, sockets, c++11

I'm writing a c++ client. The client connects to the server with TCP protocol successfully and sends data too. I wrote the code below to receive data :

```
char data[9];
int received_size = recv(fd, data, 9, flags);
std::string str{ data };
// str.empty() is true
```

Which flags is MSG_NOSIGNAL.

The problem is that after execution of this line the received_size is 9 but the data length is zero.

Comment: How are you determining the length of the data?  Are you (erroneously) using C-string or similar functions that stop at the first null byte to determine the length?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie  in this state i know the length of packet my server send. i wnat to know reason of this strange behavior of recv function

Comment: You didn't answer my question.  How are you determining (in code) that the data is "empty"?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie the question code is updated.

Comment: Well, your latest edit answers the question.  You're stopping at the first null byte.  The constructor for `std::string` that takes a pointer does just that.  So your observations are not correct.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If `recv` is returning a value, then that is the number of bytes received.

The issue is that you're using the wrong functions to determine the data that you're receiving.  The `std::string` constructor that you're using will stop at the first null byte, irrespective of the number of actual bytes `recv` returned.

Instead, use the other version of the `std::string` constructor that takes a byte length:

```
char data[9];
int received_size = recv(fd, data, 9, flags);
std::string str(data, received_size);
```

Answer (score 4):

You are expecting the received data to be zero-terminated. Which is a wrong expectation because it can receive incomplete data. The correct way is to use `received_size` (after error checking has been done):

```
std::string str(data, received_size);
```

That still is not enough in real-world applications. You need to [delimit messages somehow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6946109/4120800).

Answer (score -3):

If you need to deal with zero bytes, use `std::vector<unsigned char>` instead of `std::string`:

```
char data[9];
int received_size = recv(fd, data, 9, flags);
std::vector<unsigned char> str( std::begin(data), std::begin(data)+received_size );
std::cout << str.size() << '\n';
```